# C# - Calculate Sum of Surrounding Characters in a list of Strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

Lets Say I have 4 strings in a `List<string>`. I have used x y and z as an example here but could be any character.

```
"xyyy",
"yyyz",
"yyxz",
"yyyy"
```

How would I go about calculating the position of the of the SURROUNDING Y in terms of x in this list of strings ? So target X  and calculate all touching Y points , note that I Wish to ignore z and only target y in this case. In the case of x in the top left part it would be 3 touching y points

I started iterating through the string by using `ToCharArray()` and keeping track of the lower and upper bounds of where I am in the list but it quickly becomes recursion hell. Im looking for better solution to iterating through every list and checking if it has a below and upward bound and then iterating through all chars.

For clarifications sake :

Lets zoom on the first two strings in the list

```
"xyyy",
"yyyz"
```

We can clearly see that x touches the y to the right,diagonally and one below it which means 3 touching ys in total.

I would then have to output to console the amount of times x touched y PER string in the list - in other words : per line

Comment: There is more than one x. What do you want to do then, or do you want to just throw an exception, and delete C drive when this happens

Comment: isn't it 2 touching y points ... in the first `"xyyy"` and the third `"yyxz"` ?

Comment: Yes I need to iterate through every char in the list of strings and find all surrounding ys when i hit char x @TheGeneral

Comment: It's really hard to provide an answer since I cannot understand your problem here. So if you can provide more details we will be able to help you

Comment: @AhmedSherien no the x touches y right bottom and diagonal

Comment: I will update with more details.

Comment: Does the location of the touching Ys matter to the output or just the count?

Comment: @Naate just the count would be fine - bonus points for location :P

Comment: It should be pretty easy find index of x and check its neighbours

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I had the same thought but am unsure how to approach this using neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the row length, and you know the index of the target(found by scanning the whole array for x, then it is trivial to compute the index of the adjacent squares

```
int i= //some index;
int l= //row length;
int y = i/l;//the floored quotient is the y offset
int x = i % l;//the remainder is the x offset

//Note that a negative result or a number greater than the whole array length is illegal so you have to catch that in your logic
int n= i-w;// skip a row back
int s = i+w;// skip a row forward
//if we hit the end then illegal else adjacent
int e= x+1 ==l? -1 : i+1;  
int w= x-1 <0? -1: i-1;
```

//If you don't want to convert the list of string into a 2D array, just go line by line as above but y now simply becomes the index into your Lst, while x is a scan of the string. When you find the target character its adjacent values will be:

```
char n = list[y-1][x];
char s = list[y+1][x];
char e = list[y][x+1];
char w = list[y][x-1];
char sw= list[y+1][x-1];
char se= list[y+1][x+1];
//etc.
```

Just remember to check the bounds, just `catch IndexOutOfRange`, and continue the loop, to avoid lots of tedious specialized check logic.

Those are my back of the napkin calculations, you might want to check with a picture.  Also if you want diagonals I leave that as an exercise. Hint: use the same logic with the newly produced indices.

If you have the character values there are plenty of examples of summing them, I assume the difficult part was finding adjacency.

Comment: You are absolutely correct , finding adjacent ones is not the main problem, but traversing down the string that came before and after and finding the diagonals is the issue im facing.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood how you've converted to a char array, I'll convert my code to accommodate not make the list into a 2d array.

Comment: I have been tinkering with his . It is exactly what i needed thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough implementation of what you've described you want.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Touching {

    class CharFinder {

        public static List<Tuple<int, int>> counted = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            getInputs(out char target, out char indexed, out List<string> lines);
            List<Tuple<int, int>> indexes = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i != lines.Count; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j != lines[i].Length; j++) {
                    if (lines[i][j] == indexed) {
                        indexes.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));
                    }
                }
            } int tCount = countNeighbor(lines, indexes[0], target);
            for (int i = 0; i != indexes.Count; i++) {
                tCount += countNeighbor(lines, indexes[i], target);
            } Console.WriteLine(tCount.ToString()); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int countNeighbor(List<string> grid, Tuple<int, int> ind, char target) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = ind.Item1 - 1; i < ind.Item1 + 2; i++) {
                if (i == -1 || i >= grid.Count) { continue; } 
                for (int j = ind.Item2 - 1; j < ind.Item2 + 2; j++) {
                    if (j == -1 || j >= grid[i].Length) { continue; }
                    if (grid[i][j] == target && !counted.Contains(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j))) { 
                        counted.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));
                        count++; 
                    }
                }
            } return count;
        }

        public static void getInputs(out char target, out char indexed, out List<string> strs) {
            int lines = 0;
            strs = new List<string>();
            while (true) {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Number of lines?: ");
                try { lines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); if (lines < 1) { throw new Exception(); } break; }
                catch { Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Must be a positive integer."); Console.ReadLine(); }
            } Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Target?: ");
            target = Console.ReadLine()[0];
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Indexed?: ");
            indexed = Console.ReadLine()[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
                strs.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```